# Splashscreen - getActionBar().hide still flashes for a second

Tags: android, hide, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, visible

I am trying to implement a splashcreen and I dont want to use a new activity for the splashscreen,

So I set visibility=gone on my listview, hide actionbar, leave the logo visibility=visible, sleep for a certain period and then show the actionbar again and set the listview visibility back to visible

This works, however there is a brief moment at the start when the actionbar is still visible before it gets hidden

Is there a way to fix this and have the actionbar be gone from the beginning?

I am using ActionBarSherlock and Galaxy S3 with 4.1 Jelly Bean.

Thanks

Comment: Why complicate things when you can get a much easier solution by creating a new activity? I know that you don't want it that way. But why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way to do this without using two separate activities.

The action bar is initialized as part of the decor view which happens much earlier than your `onCreate` method. This means there will be the noticeable lag that you describe before it can be hidden. If you wanted to permanently hide it you could do so using a theme or window flag but once you do that there is no way to get it to appear.

Comment: Okay thanks, thats what I was using before (flag no titlebar) but then I just dont like the way actionbar flashes into place when the other activity starts, okay nevermind, Ill just look into transition animations between activites. Thanks!